# Isn't ASP.NET MVC _layout.cshtml similar to Webforms Master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC 4 project with a layout page that I have setup with images that are links like this

```
 <a href="/"><img id="logoImage" src="~/Content/siteImages/myLogo.png" alt="My logo"    title="Welcome to my site" /></a>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<a href="/"><img id="logoImage" src="../Content/siteImages/myLogo.png" alt="My logo" title="Welcome to my site" /></a>
```

And this:

```
<a href="/"><img id="logoImage" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/siteImages/myLogo.png")" alt="My logo" title="Welcome to my site" /></a>
```

These all work fine as long as the controller is the home controller. I use an Actionlink `@Html.ActionLink("Northwind Demo", "Northwind", "Northwind", null, new { @class="links"})` to get to another controller.

As soon as the ActionLink is clicked, my images disappear. I examined the rendered link text in the browser and it is the same as it was before.

`src="Content/siteImages/myLogo.png"`

However, when examining the request in the network tab of the browser the url for the image is now 
`Northwind/Content/siteImages/myLogo.png`

which does not resolve. For some reason the browser is adding the name of the controller to the beginning of the request for the image. I am sure that I am missing something really dumb but...
How do I fix this?

**Edit**
I wonder if this is an issue that only happens when running locally and may disappear when deployed to a server? I am still unable to fix this.

**Edit**
I am really struggling with the fact that no one else has encountered this before. I was under the impression that _layout.cshtml was like a master page in WebFroms. I need some suggestions here.

**EDIT**
So I had a moment of success. I changed the name of the entry method into the Northwind controller to Index and the images displayed properly in the index view. However, if I call another view, then the images disappear again. 
I use radion buttons to select a different view based on which one is selected like this:

```
public ActionResult Search()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["radio"]);

        switch (id)
        {
            case 1:
                return View("Customer");
            case 2:
                return View("Orders");
            case 3:
                return View("Employees");
            default:
                ViewBag.Error = "Search parameter not found";
                return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

I am still not able to fix this but I think that I am closer to a solution with someone's help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. I am not using areas.

Comment: what happens when you use this overload? `@Html.ActionLink("text","action","controller",null)`

Comment: The actual link that I am using: `@Html.ActionLink("Northwind Demo", "Northwind", "Northwind", null, new { @class="links"})` I was trying to be ambiguous but I entered my Action link wrong. Sorry, I will edit my original question.

Comment: Not an answer but make sure while troubleshooting that you strictly use `@Url.Content("~/...")`

Comment: I actually have several images on the page and while this is not fixed  I am using all the above techniques to see what is happening or what may work or not. MVC 4 is supposed to be able to use the ("~/...") to resolve links.

Comment: @mxmissile - Url.Content is not required when using Razor 2 or greater, it's only required in Razor 1 or WebForms ViewEngine

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch nice! I did not know that, good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have figured this out and I feel like an idiot! I have a script file that I use to change the images when it becomes small enough so that they continue to fit on the screen as it gets smaller for a responsive design. Like this:

```
$("#logoImage").attr("src", "Content/siteImages/logoSmall.png");
```

Well, the missing / at the very beginning is what was causing the issue. Adding the / fixed all my issues. Like this:

$("#logoImage").attr("src", "/Content/siteImages/logoSmall.png");

Even though I feel very silly at this moment, I am posting my answer in case someone else comes along and has a similar issue. Don't forget your script files and don't leave anything out when trying to fix a weird issue. Thanks to everyone that looked at this and tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use relative addressing in MVC, since as you can tell you run into problems because views can be accessed from multiple routes (ie, `/`, `/Home`, `/Home/Index`, etc.. are all the same view, but different paths, if you use `../whatever` then `/Home/Index` becomes `/Home/whatever`, `/` and `/Home` become `/whatever`)

Always use either `@Url.Content` to generate urls if you're not in a Razor 2+ view.  If you're in Razor 2 or greater, then you can use `src="~/Content/images/whatever"`

If these methods are not working, then you need to look at your Application root, web.config, etc.. because MVC is becoming confused about where the root of the site is.

Comment: I have tried both `@Url.Content` and `src="~/Content/...` and both render the link to the browser fine. The real problem is that the request that is being made back to the server for the image is `"SomeControllerName/Content/...`. This only happens if it is not the home controller that the view is being served from. ???

Comment: @Trucktech - You seem to have something weird configured there.. how are your routes configured?

Comment: I have only the default route. I wouldn't think that routing should play a role in this. Once _layout.cshtml is called from another controller it seems to add the controller name to the request for the images that are located on _layout.cshtml. But the rendered links look ok. Only the request to fetch the images shows the controller name. Weird. I am used to Web Forms so this is very strange for me.

Comment: @Trucktech - have you created any virtual folders in your IIS structure with web.config's in them?

Comment: No. This is happening when running from Visual Studio. That is a part of the question I posted. Maybe only a local issue?